# Django MEDIA_ROOT pointed to network drive

Tags: python, django, windows, file-upload, network-drive

I'm trying to get files uploaded through the Django admin site to be placed on a network drive. Lets say the path to this drive is '\\FILESERVER\Django'.

My initial thought was to just set my media root to the same path I'd use to access the drive via File Explorer:

```
#settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = r'\\FILESERVER\Django'
```

An Example Model:

```
#models.py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='articles', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

But when I upload a file, It just creates the folder on my local C: drive. 
(e.g. C:\FILESERVER\Django\articles). Is there a way I can tell Django that this is supposed to be a path to a network drive?

**Note:** This is a Django 2.0.4 app running on a windows machine.

Comment: Have you tried to point it out to the internal IP address of the network drive? [Here's](https://superuser.com/questions/1034595/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-of-a-mapped-network-drive-in-windows-10) how you can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is in `pathlib`. Have a look here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods-and-properties

Something like `PureWindowsPath('//FILESERVER/Django').drive` should do the trick for `MEDIA_ROOT`, IIRC.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thanks!

Comment: How are you fetching the files after uploaded into the network drive using django??

Answer (score 0):

If you use a network file server,you may need  a customized django file storage class.